# How to change Content-Location header in SDR association resource?

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

In my Spring project I'm using neo4j as the database layer, and as it's own GraphId is not entirely reliable, I am using textual ids (e.g. email address for users) for my nodes.

I can change the HATEOAS links in my response resources, and they work fine. **Is there a way to change the link in the Content-Location header as well?**

Comment: As long as you assign id in code somewhere before SDR calls on save on repository you should be good

Comment: I want to use a different field in the links (and headers), not the database id.

Comment: SDR wires the ID links with what is on set on "Id" field. I doubt you could override that. However you have option of add additional links.